# Better practices for arrays and function calls

Tags: php

I'm in search of an answer for what is the better practice of the php language. I have the following piece of code. Is it better to send a list of parameters to the output function for display or should I form an array for the output function to display. If you have a comment or answer please provide any documentation that supports your answer so anyone including myself can view this material in the future. I have included the output function to show how I output messages to the browswers however I am considering using flashdata for display however what makes me wonder how I would use that when I have different types of messages for example info, warning, success messages.

```
if (!$this->form_is_valid())
{
    $this->output('The form did not validate successfully!', 
                    'Form Not Validated', 'Error');
    return;
}

public function output($message, $title, $status)
{
    switch (strtoupper($status))
    {
        default:
        case 'ERROR':
            $status = 'Error';
            break;
        case 'NOTICE':
            $status = 'Notice';
            break;
        case 'SUCCESS':
            $status = 'Success';
            break;
    }
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode(array
        (
        'output_status' => $status,
        'output_title' => $title,
        'output_message' => $message)));
}
```

Comment: The return is unnecessary. Without the definition of the form_is_valid or the output methods it's hard/impossible to make any meaningful assessment.

Comment: I updated my answer to better assist you with a possible answer.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be valid. `$this->output` is defined as a function but you are calling a method on it `$this->output->set_content_type`

Comment: Oops. That's true. I need to change that function name so it doesn't cause an error down the road with having the same name as a Codeigniter class.

Comment: If I decide to drop the ajax json return array and display flash data instead then I'm going to wonder how to complete the function call only because I have 3 different types of messages: notices, errors, and success messages and if i set the flash data up so tht it displays the message its not going to know what type of message to display other than the title and content of the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better option would be to pass an object to the output method:

```
<?php
interface Message
{
  public function getContents();
  public function getSummary();
  public function getType();
}

abstract class AbstractMessage() implements Message
{
  protected $type;
  protected $contents;
  protected $summary;

  protected function __construct($contents, $summary) {
    $this->contents = $contents;
    $this->summary = $summary;
  }

  public function getContents() {
    return $this->contents;
  }

  public function getSummary() {
    return $this->summary;
  }

  public function getType() {
    return $this->type;
  }
}

class ErrorMessage() extends AbstractMessage
{
  public function __construct($contents, $summary) {
    parent::__construct($contents, $summary);
    $this->type = 'Error';
  }
}

class InfoMessage() extends AbstractMessage
{
  ...
}

...

if (!$this->form_is_valid())
{
  $this->output(new ErrorMessage(
    'The form did not validate successfully!', 
    'Form Not Validated',
    'Error'
  ));
  return;
}
```